# Post request to webhook without redirecting

Tags: javascript, node.js, webhooks

How can I make a post request (after validating some user input) to a webhook without redirecting the user to the webhook url?

Answer (score 0):

Tis kind of request is generally done using AJAX.

If you are using jQuery, you should look at [.post()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) method. See an exemple of it:

```
$.post( "/url.html", function( data ) {
    # action on request response
});
```

If you are using raw javascript (without js libs), you should look at XMLHttpRequest() object. Example of use:

```
var post = function() {
    var url = "http://www.example.com";
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open( "POST", url, true);
    request.send(null);   
}
```

Using this approach of request you will not be redirect, like the common case of HTML submitions.